# Testing Redis transaction with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, transactions, redis

I am using a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC command sequence to complete a transaction in a Rails app. I'd like to spec out the behavior of the app both when the transaction succeeds and the transaction fails (specifically when the watched key is modified in another session during the transaction).

Concretely speaking, given the (contrived) example below, how might I write a spec that always modifies `testval` in Redis while the arbitrary computation is being performed?

```
def test_watch
  REDIS.watch("testval") do
    val = REDIS.get('testval')
    val += 1000 # arbitrary computation
    REDIS.multi do |m|
      REDIS.set('testval', val)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to modify your key 'testval' in another session, you can do it in the same session and your transaction will still fail. So you just need to find a way to inject a REDIS.set('testval', some_value) between the watch and multi and your transaction will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I understand correctly, it means I can use watch/multi/exec as part of my program logic (instead of only a concurrency tool) by conditionally changing the watched value. I am still mainly interested in how to actually inject the REDIS.set statement though.

Comment: This is what I would probably do: encapsulate the Redis client in your own class providing just the methods that you actually need. You can do it generic to be just a CacheClient. Then I would do a child class (by inheritance) something called TransactionFailCacheClient and I would only override the GET method to actually do a GETSET on Redis. Then I would use a Service Locator in order to use the TransactionFailCacheClient for the tests where you want your transaction to fail http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator